# Are flags once rejected get "rejected forever" or can they be reconsidered?

Tags: support, moderators, flagging

Suppose one flag is rejected by one of the Moderators. Does that mean it has attained a "permanently rejected status"?

Or some other Moderator can still revisit/reconsider it and accept it (or even reject it) later?

Comment: No, it can't be undone i.e once your flag is rejected, it will remain the label/status rejected forever. Though the issue raised by flag can be reconsidered.

Comment: Ok so can u write the answer? @Pandya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, once flag marked as helpful or rejected by a moderator can't be undone. In other words, the flag label/status is permanent/forever.

Though the issue raised by flag can be reconsidered by talking to moderators via chat or re-flagging

Comment: So, we can flag more than once any particular post even though it was rejected once?

Comment: @Rickross - you can't raise a second red flag (spam or rude/abusive) after you've already raised one red flag on that post. You can't raise another recommend deletion flag (very low quality and not an answer) after you've already flagged it once. You can't raise a closure flag as far as I am aware more than once. But you can raise a 'in need of moderator intervention' flag after raising any kind of flag. I'm not aware of any limits on how many times you can flag the same post for moderator attention.